# How can I use QIAGEN Ingenuity Pathway Analysis (IPA) on proteomics data associated with an outcome?

Tags: gsea, pathway

I am trying to do pathway analysis on a set of proteins associated with several outcomes (one is continuous, the others four are binary). I have run independent associations between the proteomics data and the outcomes in question and have ascertained betas, hazard ratios, p values, and associated multiple-testing correction p-values. Out of the set of 3000 proteins for which we have proteomics data, we have found significant FDR corrected associations with our outcomes in ~1800. I am trying to do pathway analysis with these proteins.

I am trying several pathway analysis approaches, including `fgsea`, online GSEA through GenePattern, and Ingenuity Pathway Analysis. For the GSEA approaches, I have been able to generate the ranked list and provide the ranked list to the software. However, it is my understanding that IPA is a form of overrepresentation analysis and therefore I should not provide a ranked list. However, when uploading my dataset to the IPA application, it asks for expression change values (my understanding is that all these approaches were originally designed for microarray-based  differential expression data).

Since we are looking at the association between proteomics and several outcomes, expression change values are not relevant to these data. However, the directionality of the effect is relevant when considering pathways, and since we have the betas for the association it seems to me that I should include it. I looked through the IPA documentation and all of it seems specific to differential expression analysis. Can anyone point me in the correct direction to perform IPA on the association between my outcomes and proteomics data? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you already asked Qiagen about this? IPA is a very expensive product; Qiagen should at least provide good support around the bioinformatics side of things because bioinformatics is such a core part of their product.